# Responsive Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

In creating reusable components for communities I have come up against a bit of a challenge with layout. Let's say I am designing a simple table. When a user places this table in a main layout column, I would like it to display as a normal table does. However, if placed in a sidebar or viewed on a narrower device it should reflow to display rows as cards. A responsive layout with respect to viewport size can be accomplished with media queries, but CSS does not support element queries yet.

Has anyone solved this problem in lightning in a reusable fashion or had luck bringing in a third party library such as EQCSS (http://elementqueries.com/) to accomplish this? Is current best practice to have a design attribute that users must choose their layout type instead of it being dynamically determined based on placement?

Comment: I have a similar question here that has yet to get an answer that works: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155296/lightning-component-grid-sizing-narrow-right-side-of-lightning-page

Comment: @Eric If I don't get any info on here I am going to just try a number of the third party libraries to see if there are any that don't require a complete rewrite of SLDS to work.

Answer (score 1):

They made the media queries even easier to access with the visibility classes.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/visibility/#flavor-responsive

You can use the combination of below classes to hide or show items.

[image: Salesforce visibility media queries]

you can display your results in three different items

large and medium tables

`<table class="slds-medium-show"></table>`

small cards

`<div class="slds-small-show-only"></div>`

really small cards

`<div class="slds-x-small-show-only"></div>`

hope this helps.

Comment: Those utility classes are still using the viewport size though, right?

Comment: @dsharrison Correct. So if you component lives in a small region (for instance a sidebar) you'd still have issues, even though the viewport size could be large.

Comment: If only they placed a link to this in the LDS Grid section! I was looking for this and didn't notice this section at all. Thanks @Sid!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lightning design system which provides a full grid for you.

Comment: Is their grid system based off of container size and not device size? I looked at the scss source code and I only saw media queries in there.

Comment: I am not 100% sure. Might be worth just trying it in a small POC

Comment: @JannisBott - Grid sizing unfortunately does not work properly when in the narrow right side or lightning page until the window is narrowed