# Lightning components: how to make component aware of position on record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to render two different views depending on where my component is placed on a record page from Lightning App Builder. Is there an attribute or something that I could pass into an aura:if?

Here's a visual example of what I'm talking about: let's say that my component is the section that says 'collaborate with others'... I wan't the component to be able to tell the difference between

[image: sidebar view]

and

[image: horizontal view]

Comment: This sounds very similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155296/lightning-component-grid-sizing-narrow-right-side-of-lightning-page and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163479/responsive-lightning-components but neither of those have a good answer yet.

Comment: Why not just using width and create a responsive component ? With custom templates on the roadmap, it may not be as easy as it is now to have information about the position.

Comment: In Winter '18 there is a new component named lightning:flexipageRegionInfo that may help you: "Provides Lightning page region information to the component that contains it."